# Vaadin Valo Stylesheets

Tags: css, tomcat, vaadin, vaadin-valo-theme

I'm having a problem using Vaadin (in Eclipse) and its associated styling engine Valo, and the TouchKit package. I mention all of these because I'm not sure which, if any, is causing the problem. The name of my custom theme (which imports Valo) is simply "touchkit".

I have the project running on a Tomcat server on localhost and accessible in my browser. I wanted to tweak some of the CSS so I edited the appropriate file `WebContent/VAADIN/themes/touchkit/touchkit.scss`. After editing this file, I recompile the theme and see the appropriate changes in the generated file `styles.css`. Then I go to load up the application in my browser, and things get weird.

I can load the page and, using Chrome's developer tools, see that the page requests styles.css for download, as expected. It gets a 200 OK response from the server, but when I view `styles.css`, it contains just a single `\n`. This is also true in Safari. Even using cURL to download `styles.css` yields the same result. In the Eclipse editor, and when I inspect it in the terminal, styles.css is ~12,000 lines long. Why can't my browser or cURL get that data?

I can view similar project demos on Vaadin's own site and the stylesheet (which should be almost identical to mine) is loaded correctly. Also, other Vaadin projects on my localhost server have their stylesheets loaded correctly (though they do not use Valo). Compiling the theme in Eclipse yields no errors. Because the issue presents itself across a variety of graphical and non-graphical clients, I'm starting to think the issue is with Tomcat. But I can get to the directory from which Tomcat serves files and `styles.css` is correct in that folder too. There's no apparent reason that Tomcat would be serving a blank file.

You may have guessed from the description, but I'm working on a Mac. Any help is appreciated!

PS Mods - I also asked this question over at Superuser since it wasn't 100% a programming question. However, I'm new at Superuser and couldn't create tags for Vaadin or Valo, so I'm asking here where there might be a better chance of getting an answer.

Comment: your logging is sane and you don't eat up somewhere an exception?  is your app running in production mode (a flag for the servlet)?  does chrome/curl -i show odd things in the headers?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say, since your are doing everything fine. My best bet would be the tomcat implementation you are using, maybe there's something weird there. Try upgrading to latest if it's not or to a previous version.
FYI I'm using Tomcat 7.0.55.

PS: your attempts are in run/debug from eclipse or have you made a .war form the project and deployed it with the Tomcat-Manager?

Regards

Answer (score 0):

add below to your gwt.xml, and touchkit is not valo aware see https://vaadin.com/forum/#!/thread/8264224/8264223

```
 <set-configuration-property
        name='touchkit.manifestlinker.additionalCacheRoot'
        value='src/main/webapp/VAADIN/themes/MyTheme:../../../VAADIN/themes/MyTheme' />
```